# FaceBook Login with Other Username

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, facebook-ios-sdk

I have a problem with Facebook login. I create app on my Facebook id, and from my app i am able to login and  get user Inforamtion. it works properly with my Facebook username. But when I am Login with other user name in Facebook and get data it not working. Why it's work for me.but not other user.

it shows the following error.

[image: fberror]

if i login with my Id then it works properly.

please help me. what is the problem?

Comment: did you try with 2-3 more ids.

Comment: yes i try with 5 ids but work for only my id

Comment: see below screnshot. thats what i was saying

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set sandbox mode to no in your application settings in facebook.

Comment: means it set to Off(disabled)?

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Check in your app settings -> sandbox mode

Answer (score 0):

Problem might be that new user havent given permissions to your application to get data.
Verify that when a new user log in. Ask for basic permission then attempt to get data.